# A multiplayer board game catching eggs down a chute with a cart

Tags: identify-this-game

A multiplayer board game catching eggs down a chute with a cart

All of the information I can provide is from a very vague memory:

I believe the game is from the 90's. It is possible it's slightly earlier, or early 2000's.
From memory, it is a four player game.
Each player was assigned a chute/slide that were all colored differently.
(blue, red, green, yellow)
Attached to each player's chute was a cart (same colored) with a nest on top. 
When the player would push their cart towards their chute, the chute would lift up and change it's angles, as the chute had hinges.
The chute had to move the correct angles to safely get their (plastic) eggs down their chute into their cart.
From there, the cart was tilted into the collection area beside the original position of the cart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've got it - is this [Pickin' Chickens](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/8035/pickin-chickens)?

Comment: Yes!!! Pickin' Chickens! It looks like my memory is far off, but that is the game I was trying to remember. This game was difficult to search because another game has this name, but it is completely different. Thank you so much, Ben! 8 )